# Is there a length cap?

Tags: slither.io

It seems to me that after cresting 20-25k, I don't get noticeably larger. I've gotten up to 80k without noticing any real gains. Does anyone know for sure? It's hard to tell whether I'm imagining it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the length cap is 40k. Your snake will not be longer or fatter after reaching the score of 40k, but you score can still continue to increase.